# Flutter Windows: how can we add Header and footer in same code while we have code for mobile?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-windows

I have flutter 2.10 SDK but there is no documentation on native web Replacements. please anyone throw light on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to execute code based on the host platform.

First import the relevant headers

```dart
import 'dart:io' show Platform;
```

Using Platform APIs now you can detect the host platform and execute your codes for target platforms:

```dart
void myCode() {
  if (Platform.isWindows) {
    // do something specific for Windows here
  } else {
    // do something for other platforms
  }
}
```